# How to calculate sensitivity of multiple features in regression model

Tags: python, random-forest

Sensitivity might be bad word for what I mean as I have not found the results that I am looking for when searching for it.

So I have created a regression model using Random Forests. I then used different methods for selecting features, narrowing the amount of features down from 60 to 9.

In the model you get the output 'Y', or 'N'. Either you are approved or denied, respectivly. What I would like to do now is that if you get the output 'N' you should also get how much you can improve in each feature to get 'Y'.

For example the output could be: " You were denied, however if you increase you x1 score with 0.1, x2 with 0.5, x3 with 1 and x4 with -5, you would have been approved." In other words, how much can the features change in order to change the label of the output.

Assume that the variables are not correlated.

The way that I have been doing now is to for loop for each feature, changing it a bit in each iteration and stoping when the label change. However, this lead to multiple for loops in for loops, which does not seem optimal. Is there any function in python that does this, or is there any easier way?

Thank you :)

Comment: I consider this question is off topic for stackoverflow, since it is not a question about programming, but rather a Data Science question. The question is also quite complicated because of nonlinearities in random forests. I suggest you head over to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead and see if you can get a good answer there.

Comment: Thank you, I was jumping back and forth between several stack sites. Will look there as well :)